# detect pagination condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I want to get the condition of action pagination that's why i define this in my grid i want how can i define variable to test if the action is paginator or not :

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "function (s,e){Test123(s,e)}";
```

And now when i want to test if action is pagination i display an alert:

```
function Test123(s, e) {
        debugger;
        var xx = ListeClient.cpPageChanged;
        alert(xx);
    }
```

**it display undefined**
How can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't want quotes around your function definition, because you almost never `eval` a string in Javascript (but I don't know what API you're working with, so I can't say for sure):

`settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = function (s,e){Test123(s,e)};`

The other problem could be that this line

`var xx = ListeClient.cpPageChanged;`

*is* undefined. Then your problem is that `cpPageChanged` is not a property of `ListeClient`, so you might just have a typo.